# SDXC/microSDXC memory card reader for older Linux kernels

Tags: linux, microsd, memory-card, sdxc

Requirements:

- Works properly with Linux 4.9 kernel
- Easy to insert/remove card
- SDXC card support (64-128GB cards)
- SDHC card support

Nice to have features:

- USB 3.0 interface/speed
- Separate slot for SD and microSD cards (no need for an adapter)

I have tried a few SD card readers but none of them worked properly with older Linux kernels/distributions. Usually they recognized the reader and the memory card but there were unreadable files and IO errors. As far as I remember they worked well with Windows so I guess it was a driver bug in Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Kingston FCR-MLG4 MobileLite G4](https://www.kingston.com/en/flash/readers/fcr-mlg4) works well for me.

> Works properly with Linux 4.9 kernel

Works well with Debian Stretch (Linux kernel 4.9) and Ubuntu 17.10 (kernel 4.16).

> Easy to insert/remove card

It fairly easy. (I found that easier than both Kingston FCR-MRG2 Generation 2 micro SD Reader and Kingston FCR-ML MobileLite 9-in-1 Card Reader).

> SDXC card support (64-128GB cards)
>   SDHC card support

Works well with a variety of SD cards. I have tested it with sizes between 2GB-64GB without any issue.

> USB 3.0 interface/speed

Yes, it supports USB 3.

> Separate slot for SD and microSD cards (no need for an adapter)

It has separate SD and microSD size slots. Additionally, both work at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Kingston Digital USB 3.0 Super Speed Multi-Card Reader for SD/SDHC/SDXC/microSD/MS/Compact Flash CF Cards (FCR-HS4)

Manufacturer page: https://www.kingston.com/US/flash/readers/FCR-HS4
Amazon page: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00VAGX6MW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VAGX6MW)

Meets all your requirements and I have used it successfully with Linux Kernels beginning with 4.4, 4.8, 4.10, and several newer kernels.

It is fast and reliable with all cards I have used up to 256GB.